# Appending an array to a binary file

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, append, binaryfiles

Hi there I have been having trouble appending entered data to the end of a binary file, having looked up how to do so I found a solution here on stack overflow:

```
try {
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream ("BinaryWrite.hagl", true));
    out.writeObject(allTowns);
    out.flush ();
    }
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("IMPOSSSIBLE");
    }
```

In this piece of code allTowns is my array in which the data I wish to add is held. The problem I am getting is that when I run my program and it displays what is in the file at the end this piece of code never writes to the file at all, I was wondering if anyone could help me understand why this does not work or even just recommend a different method if necessary.

My full code (this part is currently commented out so one can easily create the file):

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
 public class CoastaslTowns implements Serializable
{

public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String name, county;
int population, area;
public static int count = 0;
public static int continuation = 0;
public static CoastaslTowns[] allTowns = new CoastaslTowns[50];
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int loop1 = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 50; i++) {
        allTowns[i] = new CoastaslTowns();
    }

    while (loop1 == 0) {

        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the town.");
        String nameEntered = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the county in which the town resides.");
        String countyEntered = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the population of the town.");
        int populationEntered = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the area of the town.");
        int areaEntered = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Are you satisfied with your entries?");
        String satisfaction = input.nextLine();
        if (satisfaction.equals("yes")) {
            loop1 = 5; 
            System.out.println("Thank you for entering your details");
            continuation = 1;

        }
        else if (satisfaction.equals("no")) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to continue and enter more towns?");
            String countychecker = input.nextLine();
            if (countychecker.equals("yes")) {

            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        writeToFile(nameEntered, countyEntered, populationEntered, areaEntered); 
    }   
    ReturnTowns();
}

public static void inputVariations(){
}

public static void writeToFile(String nameEntered, String countyEntered, int populationEntered, int areaEntered) {


    int loop2 = 0;
    while (loop2 == 0){
        allTowns[count].population = populationEntered;
        allTowns[count].name = nameEntered; 
        allTowns[count].county = countyEntered;
        allTowns[count].area = areaEntered;
        if (continuation == 1) {
            loop2 = 1;

        }
        else {
            loop2 = 1;
        }
        count = count + 1;
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("BinaryWrite.hgal");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(allTowns);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (IOException i) {}

    /*
    try {
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream ("BinaryWrite.hagl", true));
    out.writeObject(allTowns);
    out.flush ();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("IMPOSSSIBLE");
    }
     */

}
public static void ReturnTowns(){
    {

        int x = 0;
        CoastaslTowns[] bw = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn =
                new FileInputStream("BinaryWrite.hgal");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            bw = (CoastaslTowns[]) in.readObject();

            while (bw[x].population != 0) {
                System.out.println(bw[x].name);
                System.out.println(bw[x].county);
                System.out.println(bw[x].population);
                System.out.println(bw[x].area);
                System.out.println();
                x++;

            }

            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (IOException i) {
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
        }
    }
}

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot append to an ObjectOutputStream. Either you read the file and rewrite the whole stream, or you create your own protocol/file format.

Comment: Put `i.printStackTrace()` and `c.printStackTrace()` in the last catch blocks. There might be some exception there that your code is ignoring!

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes you can, but this code isn't doing any appending whatsoever.

Comment: I would just print text as a line to the end of a text file.  This would be easier to check/edit and you can append to the end easily.

Comment: @RobinGreen You are right technically that you can append, but you can't read it with ObjectInputStream.